# Add product dropdown selected value as cart item meta data in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html-select, cart

Based on *"[Add dropdown to products and display the value on Woocommerce cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098476/add-dropdown-to-products-and-display-the-value-on-woocommerce-cart/55103570#55103570)"* answer code, I'm trying to add an attribute value from a dropdown to the cart item meta data, but I don't know yet how.

```
<select id ="id_dropdown_one_end" name="dropdown_one_end">
    <option value_one_end="0">Ingenting</option>
    <option value_one_end="250">Øye       250,-</option>
    <option value_one_end="350">Sjakkel   350,-</option>
    <option value_one_end="400">Spleis    400,-</option>
</select>
```

If **`value_one_end`** attribute was named just **`value`** instead *(as by default)*, I could get the selected value with PHP using:

```
$cart_item_data['price_one_end'] = esc_attr($_POST['dropdown_one_end']);
```

But by not having a **`value`** attribute the above statement gets the name of the option instead ('Ingenting'), which is what I want.

But how do I use php to get an attribute called something else than **`value`**? I have tried something like this:

```
$cart_item_data['price_one_end'] = esc_attr($_POST['dropdown_one_end'].attr('value_one_end'));
```

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the above is not possible, is there a way to explicitly get the inner html of the <option> using PhP, even if there is a 'value' attribute?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using value_one_end in the <option> tags? … Only value is accepted in <option> html tag and will work on add to cart…

Comment: If I use 'value' in tne <option> tags ($_POST['dropdown_one_end']); will get the value attribute. How will I then get the text in the inner html?       *Edit* I guess I can use preg_replace() on the string and strip away everything except the numbers.

Comment: You can store your option value/text pairs in an array on an external simple function that you can call from everywhere. On the dropdown, you will use a foreach loop to display the formatted options. In woocommerce_add_cart_item_data hook, you will call that function too and be able to get the text from the posted value key…

Then